# Mounting a USB device in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, permissions, mount

I have a problem when trying to work with USB devices mounted with user 'root'. I explain, I mount a USB device as root under command line (console mode only), and I can work with that device with no problem, but when changing to one limited account, that device mounted is in read-only mode. I've tried to apply chmod and chown but not to work. Also, I've tried this:

```
$ sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,users /dev/sdb1 /mnt/pen/
```

and same result. How can I resolve this without using fstab file? I think there must be a solution, 'cause under X-Windows with a limited account, this USB device is recognized, mounted and worked with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the uid and gid bits to specify you as the userID which owns the file. You may also want to use umask:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/pen -o umask=022,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Under GNOME, there's an automounter (part of Gnome-VFS) that provides automounting when HAL/Dbus notifies it that a new device has become available (USB stick plugged in, CD inserted, etc).

To run a 1-off on the commandline, use the mount options `uid` and/or `gid` (and/or `umask`) as John T's answer shows.

To run a system-wide automounter, use HALevt.  See [my answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us/65095#65095) for getting HALevt to work on a headless system.  In your case, you might tweak things to run the HALevt daemon as your user.