# how get hal running on ubuntu server?

Tags: mount, dbus, hal

I want to try to create a very minimized server installation which automatically mounts its internal SATA disks. Thus, I thought of using HAL as the way to go. As far as I read, HAL is just a daemon 'listening' for hardware changes and broadcasts the changes if they match a .fdi config file via dbus to its clients.

Which client can I use on a server install? I read about `gnome-volume-manager` as a possibility but as I see, it wants to open a graphical display, which I don't need on a server install (even if it's just a software-display).

Any hints for further direction or are there any alternative dbus clients which are able to execute HAL events?

---

I got it work, but without hal/devicekit/gnome. I'm using basic udev rules and RUN commands to mount the disks

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules
# /etc/udev/rules.d/89-local.rules
# ADD rule: if we have a valid ID_FS_USAGE, and it's a filesystem with a UUID, mkdir and mount

ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="?*", ACTION=="add", RUN="/bin/mkdir -p /media/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}" RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto /dev/%k /media/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}" RUN+="/media/$env{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}/autostart.sh"
```

On Ubuntu, put this in the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/89-local.rules`. 
On Debian it should be in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. I also added the possibility to run an `autostart.sh` script during boot e.g. to start services only available on specific disks

[Automatically mount external drives to /media/LABEL on boot without a user logged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us) had the answer

Comment: ya liked my udev answer better?  that's cool too :)  note i'd put the mkdir & mount commands in a set of chained scripts so the RUN finishes *quickly* -- that's important for udev.  glad you got the boot situation figured out tho; i never really found a satisfactory solution for that.

Comment: ooo-- think i remember the *quickly* issue.  if you mount an ext2/3 filesystem that's reached it's max mount count, isn't fsck kicked off automatically?  *that* would take a while.  think there are other situations where the mount might take longer than udev would want there.

Comment: yea, thx, ill definitly have a look on this

Comment: @Udo when making edits for tag cleanup, please make sure to also check the post for anything else that needs fixing. A post like this that had lots of formatting issues, misspellings, etc. should be touched up _in full_ - don't _only_ edit the tags. Thanks.

Comment: @nhinkle: ok will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAL is a communication & message passing layer -- I'm honestly unsure of where DBus stops and HAL starts.  It's mostly used as a layer between DBus and the Desktop Environment, but it doesn't have any GUI component that requires the DE to operate.

For a headless server installation you'd want to use HALevt.  HALevt is a daemon that sits on top of HAL, much like Gnome-VFS does in the Gnome DE, and responds to hardware events.  It can be configured to run as a system-wide daemon or as an individual user.  See [an answer I wrote to an earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us/65095#65095) about using HALevt to provide Gnome-VFS-like automounting for CDs and USB drives on a headless server.  This should give you the basic how-to, although your situation would probably require some tweaking.

[whitequark's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/98428/how-get-hal-running-on-ubuntu-server/98441#98441) -- setting up your normal mounts via */etc/fstab* -- is better if your system's internal drives will not be setup for hotswapping.  Using HALevt for mounting static internal disks is doable, but more complicated than it needs to be.  But if you do have hotswap bays and you want to use them, using HALevt for automounting might be a good option for you.

Comment: also, i hear the next version of Ubuntu will be ditching HAL entirely, which makes me even *more* confused about it's specific job.  so if you're planning on upgrading to 10.04LTS when it comes out, you might consider a non-HAL-based solution.

Comment: thx, ill have a look
and just as a note: i did a bit research and it seems hal will be replaced by devicekit (http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/DeviceKit/)
so thx for the int ~quack

Answer (score 0):

Internal SATA drives cannot be *hotplugged*, i.e. plugged in while your server is powered on. So everything you need to do is mount them at powerup. For this purpose you need just place them in /etc/fstab:

1. Universal method that works for all filesystems:
   Add a line like `/dev/sdXN  /path/to/mountpoint  auto  defaults  0  2` where /dev/sdXN is your device pseudo-file.
2. Ext2/Ext3-specific method:
   First, determine name of your device file in running system. Second, get it's UUID by running `tune2fs -l /dev/sdXN | grep UUID` under root, of course replacing sdXN by your device again. Afterwards you can add a line to fstab like I did in previous paragraph but replacing first value (`/dev/sdXN`) by (`UUID=fa62e245-04bd-4cb2-a17f-5c7ee19e3574`). Of course you need to replace mine UUID with yours. This method has an advantage that if you add or remove additional SATA drives mountpoints will not be affected by the order kernel detects these devices.

Also HAL is really don't needed on any server; it's a purely desktop utility that is needed to allow unprivileged users perform some privileged operations and through D-Bus only. You probably want to use console utilites that are much more suitable for server environment.

Comment: i don't think that's true (SATA drives can't be hotplugged) -- the SATA spec provides for hotplugging, but your chipset needs to support it explicitly and you need hotplug-capable power connectors.  (this is how eSATA works, AFAIK.)

Comment: I said, not all SATA drives but only internal SATA drives, and it's unlikely that power connectors of standard internal SATA will be eSATA-compliant.

Comment: what do you think are inside those hotplug SATA caddies?  hotplug-capable internal SATA drives.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Hotplug -- "All SATA devices support hotplugging."  it does require the chipset to be in native mode (AHCI, not IDE-emulation mode).  the *power* side of things is different; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Power_supply

Comment: sorry, I actually meant "power cables that were in the box with internal drive" which are probably installed.
also this discussion probably becomes somewhat offtopic.

Comment: the reason i try to use hal instead of fstab is that fstab cant scale
which also is part of the hotplugging problem
but my main purpose is: i want a script (like .fdi) which is generalized so that i can use it on every future hardware which is based on the same rules i currently define
and fstab is just too much work and error prone for my taste in my case