# What is the workflow for automount in Gnome 2.30?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, udev

I have a ASUS laptop with Fedora 13. My problem is that any USB storage I connect does not automount. I have other computer with Fedora 13 which does not have the problem.

I have not be able to find any difference in configuration between my laptop and other computers that work.

So to try to trace down the problem I started to looomk for documentation on how it was supposed to work. I have looked at udev, devkit, hal , dbus, polkit, gnome and others.

I want to know which events, logs, config files and monitor programs that I can use to track down the events that takes place from when I attach an USB stick and until i have a window up and running in GNOME.

So far I have traced that udev detects the disk and creates /dev/sdb (and /dev/sdb1 for partition 1) and that event about device added is sent as messages on dbus. I am able to mount the disk manually with udisks but not with gnome-disk-utility (palmiset).

There is many different applications involved to automount a disk, I want to find out where in the chain of events does it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAL posts a D-Bus system message when a new volume comes up. It is up to a D-Bus client (usually nautilus) to listen for that message and request via D-Bus that HAL mount the volume.

Comment: OK, how can I monitor or verify if nautilus receives this message? Is there a log or a monitor program that I can run?

Comment: `dbus-monitor` will allow you to monitor D-Bus signals. D-Feet will allow you to introspect D-Bus interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, but that just shows that the message is issued on the dbus? How do I know if is picked up by Nautilus? Also, how do I know what messages to look for?

Comment: According to [this] (http://superuser.com/questions/53978/ubuntu-automatically-mount-external-drives-to-media-label-on-boot-without-a-us) the chain of events/programs is: kernel -> udev -> dbus -> hal -> gnome-vfs/nautilus (mount). The last step does not seem to work for me and I am wondering why. Also I believe that HAL is partly replaced by devkit/udisks in Gnome 2.30?

Comment: I just found the reason it did not mount. I had a leftover file from earlier udev version. File 60-persistent-storage.rules existed in both /etc/udev/rules.d and in /lib/udev/rules.d . The former overruled the last one. When removing the one in /etc/udev/rules.d the USB drives mounted correctly again.